# ASP.NET Core Middleware Passing Parameters to Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using `ASP.NET Core Web API`, where I have Multiple independent web api projects. Before executing any of the controllers' actions, I have to check if the the logged in user is already impersonating other user (which i can get from `DB`) and can pass the impersonated user `Id` to the `actions`.

Since this is a piece of code that gonna be reused, I thought I can use a middleware so:

- I can get the initial user login from request header
- Get the impesonated User Id if any
- **Inject that ID in the request pipeline to make it available to the api being called**

```
public class GetImpersonatorMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private IImpersonatorRepo _repo { get; set; }

    public GetImpersonatorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IImpersonatorRepo imperRepo)
    {
        _next = next;
        _repo = imperRepo;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        //get user id from identity Token
        var userId = 1;

        int impersonatedUserID = _repo.GetImpesonator(userId);

        //how to pass the impersonatedUserID so it can be picked up from controllers
        if (impersonatedUserID > 0 )
            context.Request.Headers.Add("impers_id", impersonatedUserID.ToString());

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39017590/is-it-possible-to-send-values-to-controller-from-middleware-in-aspnet-core-api), but that didn't address what I am looking for.

How can I pass a parameter and make it available in the request pipeline? Is it Ok to pass it in the header or there is more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You should change the request context, not the pipeline itself.

Comment: @LexLi, Can you please elaborate by an example, Do you mean adding some information to the request itself and get that from controller? If that what have you meant, I was thinking about that, but again where, querysting, body, wouldn't that affect the called action?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use HttpContext.Items to pass arbitrary values inside the pipeline:

```
context.Items["some"] = "value";
```

Comment: See also: [Working with HttpContext.Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state#working-with-httpcontextitems)

Comment: I'm using Session. `context.Session.SetInt32("user-id", 12345);` Which is the best approach and why?

Comment: Sessions may or not be enabled, and they require cookies.

Comment: This seems still to be the only valid solution to store values outside the middleware pipeline.

Answer (score 16):

A better solution would be to use a scoped service. Take a look at this: [Per-request middleware dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write#per-request-middleware-dependencies)

Your code should look like:

```cs
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IImpersonatorRepo imperRepo)
    {
        imperRepo.MyProperty = 1000;
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

And then register your ImpersonatorRepo as:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IImpersonatorRepo, ImpersonatorRepo>()
```

Comment: This is not working when you try to use the service per-request outside the middleware. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1#per-request-middleware-dependencies